# sorted in stream is not applicable

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this piece of Java8 code:

```
Set<Purchase> purchases = 
    user.getAcquisitions()
        .parallelStream()
        .map(a -> a.getPurchases())
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getPurchaseDate).reversed());
```

But I have this compilation error and I don't know why:

```
The method sorted(Comparator<? super Set<Purchase>>) in the type Stream<Set<Purchase>> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Comparator<Purchase>)
```

Comment: Just a question about your object model: why could an acquisition have multiple purchases?  To me the two words mean more or less the same thing.

Comment: Legacy issues :-(

Comment: I understand, and now it makes sense why you're in that mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791865/sorted-in-stream-is-not-applicable/53791892#53791892), it seems like you want a `Set<Purchase>` in sorted order (for whatever reason that may be), given you have a good reason to do so in which case you can use a `LinkedHashSet`:

```
user.getAcquisitions()
    .parallelStream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getPurchase().stream())
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getPurchaseDate).reversed())
    .collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

- `flatMap` flattens the nested `Set<Purchase>` into a `Stream<Purchase>`
- it then sorts the elements according to the provided comparator
- then collects the elements into a `LinkedHashSet` implementation which respects insertion order.

btw note that you could as well just do:

```
user.getAcquisitions()
    .parallelStream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getPurchase().stream())
    .distinct()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getPurchaseDate).reversed())
    .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

so, depending on the context you're using the resulting elements you might be better off collecting to a list implementation.

- `flatMap` flattens the nested `Set<Purchase>` into a `Stream<Purchase>`
- distinct returns a new stream of the unique objects according to the `equals` method.
- it then sorts the elements according to the provided comparator
- finally, it then collects the element from the stream into an `ArrayList` implementation.

Answer (score 9):

After `.map(a -> a.getPurchases())`, you appear to be expecting a `Stream<Purchase>`, but what you really have is a `Stream<Set<Purchase>>`.

If a `Stream<Purchase>` is indeed what you want, instead you should use

```
.flatMap(a -> a.getPurchases().stream())
```

Comment: in fact I would like a Set<Purchase>

Comment: Just collect your stream into a set then. But why do you sort your stream if you want a set? A Set is unordered so it makes no sense to sort it before collecting.

Comment: @Ricola very good point indeed!! or if they _really_ want a set with respect to the ordering then they can do `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));`

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to decide how to order two sets of purchases.  I cannot help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

The a.getPurchases() gives you a set, and your comparator is comparing elements of the set, not sets.

Based on your expected output, I understand you want to get the set which has the latest purchase date.
If each set contains only same purchase date purchases, you can create your comparator like this:

```
 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(purchases -> purchases.iterator().next(), (p1, p2) -> -p1.compareTo(p2)));
```

If purchase dates differ inside a set, you need to get max (or min) purchase date inside a set, then compare that in between the sets, something like:

```
final Stream<Set<Purchase>> sorted = acquisitions.stream()
    .map(Acquisition::getPurchases)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(purchases ->
            Collections.max(purchases, Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getPurchaseDate)).getPurchaseDate(),
            (date1, date2) -> -date1.compareTo(date2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
 Set<Purchase> purchases = 
    user.getAcquisitions()
        .parallelStream()
        .map(Acquisition::getPurchases)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: "assuming" `Purchase` is `Comparable`.